# igraph's "assortativity" function returns NaN if all attributes are identical. Why?

Tags: r, networks, social-network, igraph

I am trying to use igraph's assortativity function. It returns positive values if more similar nodes have similar attributes and negative values otherwise.

Indeed, if I randomly generate attributes for a graph, this is the case:

```
gg<-random.graph.game(50,0.3,"gnp",directed=T)
V(gg)$group<-sample(1:7,50,replace=T)
assortativity(gg, as.numeric(V(gg)$group))
[1] 0.002059966
V(gg)$group
 [1] 1 4 7 2 6 5 4 3 3 5 5 1 4 1 3 3 2 4 1 3 7 7 1 1 2 3 6 2 7 4 2 4 1 6 1 2 2 5 2 1 7 1 1 3 6 1 3 6 7 2
```

This all looks right and makes sense. However, for my dataset, I have a network for a particular situation where all the attributes are identical. Theoretically, this should be high homophily/assortativity. But to the contrary, it returns NaN. Does anyone know why this is and what the remedy could be?

```
V(gg)$group<-7
assortativity(gg, as.numeric(V(gg)$group))
[1] NaN
```

EDIT: I have found a solution to this, although I cannot explain why this is the case. It seems to be something about the whole number/integer. If I add .001 as a constant to each number in the graph's attribute, to get 7.001 instead of 7, it returns the expected assortativity coefficient of "1". See below:

```
gg<-random.graph.game(50,0.3,"gnp",directed=T)
V(gg)$group<-7
assortativity(gg, as.numeric(V(gg)$group)+rnorm(1,0,.001))
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, for my dataset, I have a network for a particular situation where all the attributes are identical. Theoretically, this should be high homophily/assortativity.

Assortativity is the Pearson correlation between values at the endpoints of edges. Note that Pearson correlation is *normalized*. If all values are the same, the expression leads to 0/0, which on a computer leads to NaN.

---

That said, I notice that you are using an attribute named "group". Is this representing the index of a group in some clustering? Are you trying to compute the tendency of vertices to connect to others within the same group? If so, you should be using `assortativity_nominal()` instead of `assortativity()`.

It makes no sense to treat a group index as a numerical quantity. It should only be used to determine whether two vertices are within the same group. This is precisely what `assortativity_nominal()` does.

The R/igraph documentation needs some work, but you can read more about what these functions do here:

- https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Structural.html#igraph_assortativity
- https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Structural.html#igraph_assortativity_nominal

Note that what R/igraph version 1.4 and earlier compute is the *normalized* version of the measure described in the above reference pages. This is what is usually referred to as "assortativity" in the literature.

Comment: "group" is a misnomer. It was a variable denoting something quantitative (although the value is from a Likert so maybe there's some sort of issue there still)